# Are methods declared in categories visible to other classes

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have the following

```
FileName : DBManager.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface DBManager : NSObject   

           //Notice no method is declared here

    @end
```

Now its implementation file looks like this

```
FileName: DBManager.m
#import "DBManager.h"

@interface DBManager()
+ (DBManager*) SomeMethod;
@end

@implementation DBManager
+ (DBManager*) SomeMethod
{
  ....
  return SomePtr;
}
@end
```

Now in some other class method if I do the following

```
[DBManager SomeMethod] ; //Error No known class method for selector 'SomeMethod'
```

However if `SomeMethod` is declared inside the .h file inside of category then this works fine. I wanted to know if this was a limitation of categories that the methods are not visible to other classes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `@interface DBManager()` is not a category, it's a class extension. There's no identifier between the parentheses.

Second, the issue isn't visibility based on whether the method is declared in a class, category, or class extension, it's whether it was declared in the same translation unit.

A translation unit is a source file after the preprocessor has included/imported the header files (or whatever other files have been included/imported).

The error is telling you that the declaration of `+SomeMethod` was not declared in the translation unit. If it were, there'd be no error, regardless of whether it were declared in the class interface, a category, or a class extension.

It follows that if you declare the interface of a category in a header file and include the header file in a source file, you can use the methods declared by that category in that source file.